# Munin mysql plugins results inconsistent, with IPC::Sharelite store() error: Identifier removed

Tags: perl, munin, ipc

I've recently setup a munin-node on a CentOS server. All was working fine until I tried to add the apache plugin (which works fine).

For some odd reason, the mysql plugins for munin that used to work ceased to work... I'm now getting a weird error whenever I'm running the plugin with munin-run. For instance

> munin-run mysql_files_tables

returns me

> IPC::ShareLite store() error: Identifier removed at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Cache/SharedMemoryBackend.pm line 156

but sometimes it will also return

> table_open_cache.value 64
>
> Open_files.value 58
>
> Open_tables.value 64
>
> Opened_tables.value 19341

but after a while it will revert to the previous error.

I do not have any knowledge about the IPC or the ShareLite library so I don't really know were to start looking. Since it is a module related to shared memory, I tried tracking down shared memory segments with *ipcs* without much success.

I haven't yet rebooted the machine as it is used for many projects (I'd obviously like to be able to diagnose the problem without requiring a restart if it was possible).

Has anyone faced this problem? (a quick search on google didn't present any relevant help)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem, but I haven't found the exact cause/source yet, so I'm still open to hear from others.

Basically, the mysql plugins of munin are written in perl, use IPC::ShareLite.

Using **strace** I was able to determine the problem is that the application gets stuck on a semop on a particular semaphore id. Using **ipcs** and **ipcrm**, I was able to remove the semaphore and get the plugin running correctly again.

**strace** gives me the **semid** as the first argument passed to **semop**. With **ipcrm -s semid**, I remove the semaphore from the system, which fixes the issue.

Thus, I'm led to believe something went wrong with the semaphore (contention maybe, but I don't see from what...).

Comment: For a more detailed "explanation", you can check the post I wrote on my blog http://www.tomrochette.com/munin-mysql-and-semaphore-how-to-deal-with-the-identifier-removed-error/.

Comment: I've the same problem on a debian/jessie (and fyi your javascript in the linked post is killing both my chromium and firefox)

Comment: @Alex, thanks for pointing that out. The problem should be resolved now. If not, let me know!

Comment: yep, both working now

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem few days ago. My solution was to replace `Cache::SharedMemoryCache` with `Cache::FileCache` in `mysql_` plugin as shown below:

```
*** mysql_      2015-12-20 15:13:12.000000000 +0100
--- mysqlnew_   2015-12-20 15:12:43.000000000 +0100
*************** use Munin::Plugin;
*** 143,149 ****
  my $has_cache;

  BEGIN {
!     eval 'require Cache::SharedMemoryCache';
      $has_cache = $@ ? 0 : 1;
  }

--- 143,149 ----
  my $has_cache;

  BEGIN {
!     eval 'require Cache::FileCache';
      $has_cache = $@ ? 0 : 1;
  }

*************** my %cache_options = (
*** 172,178 ****
  my $shared_memory_cache ;
  if ($has_cache)
  {
!   $shared_memory_cache = Cache::SharedMemoryCache->new(\%cache_options)
      or die("Couldn't instantiate SharedMemoryCache");
  }

--- 172,178 ----
  my $shared_memory_cache ;
  if ($has_cache)
  {
!   $shared_memory_cache = Cache::FileCache->new(\%cache_options)
      or die("Couldn't instantiate SharedMemoryCache");
  }
```